# How to change FlowDirection as RightToLeft in Xamarin.Forms FlyoutPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, right-to-left, flyout

I have an app it used [Xamarin.Forms FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage). It is designed to open from left side. But I also want to support the Arabic language now. That's why I want to open it from right side.
I added FlowDirection="RightToLeft" to FlyoutPage. It made aligned to right side the all text. But the side menu has not been changed to open from the right side. I applied [this right to left localization steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left) And I also changed localization settings of test devices. None of them could not changed flyout direction as right to left.

I also added following codes to xaml.cs of Flyout page. But it didn't work.

```
Flyout.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
Detail.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
```

I have seen [Xamarin.Forms Shell flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout). And I tried it with an sample project. FlowDirection="RightToLeft" command works with shell. But it will take me a lot of time to turn it into shell. (Because my app has lots of page and my all navigation will change when i change it.)

That's why I am trying to find a way to rotate side menu as right to left with Xamarin.Forms FlyoutPage. How can I do it?

EDIT: I solved this. My problem occured because of FlyoutPage CustomRenderer. I used to use custom renderer to narrow the width of my side menu. And there is a line as "GravityFlags.Left" in custom renderer. This caused problem. I understand now. I changed it as "GravityFlags.Right". Maybe it helps another person.

Comment: Hi @Pelin Konaray,  congrats，thanks for your support for xamarin. Have a nice day.